# How do I make a Rallentando/Ritardando in Guitar Pro 7.5?

Tags: composition, guitar-pro

I'd like to slow down the tempo at the end of my song - how can I achieve this in Guitar Pro 7.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tempo Automation can be found in the lefthand sidebar or through Edit -> Automations -> "Insert Tempo Automation..."

In the lefthand sidebar the icon looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the Guitar Pro 7.5 lefthand sidebar with the Tempo Automation icon circled]

To gradually change tempo rather than changing immediately, select the previous tempo marking and check the "Progressive to next point" radio button under "Transition":

[image: Screenshot of Tempo Automation Editor with previous tempo highlighted and "Progressive to next point" selected]